# How to search file and display it in list box?

Tags: c#, file, search

I am stuck with the project C# and I don't know how to solve it. I have a text file "cars.txt" and it has this information:

> 1950
>   Nissan Sentra
>   Ford Focus
>   1951
>   Mazda5
>   Mazda3
>   Toyota
>   1952
>   Chevy

I have to have 2 list boxes and one button. The first list box supposed to search through the file and populate years and when user select year and click on the button and it displays the corresponding cars models for this specific year. I have thoughts about using StreamReader but I don't know how to start.
Your help appreciated

Comment: have you went to your favorite search engine and typed: `MSDN:StreamReader`? because I'm pretty sure there is a complete example of reading in data from a textfile using the StreamReader.

Comment: You can use the static methods of `File`, like [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8). That's much easier than `StreamReader`.

Comment: I need to search only years and populated on the first list box and that what mostly I am stuck on. I know how to read all content in the file but I don't find information on how to extract only years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of string lists that will contain car lists with the year a key as well as a list for the years:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, List<string>> _carsByYear =
    new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
private readonly List<int> _years = new List<int>();
```

Then you can fill it with

```
List<string> cars = null;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Me\cars.txt")) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) {
        if (Int32.TryParse(line, out int year)) { // We have a year
            if (_carsByYear.TryGetValue(year, out var existingList)) {
                cars = existingList; 
            } else {
                 // Add a new list with year as the key
                _years.Add(year);
                cars = new List<string>();
                _carsByYear.Add(year, cars);
            }
        } else { // We have a car
            cars.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can assign `_years` to the `DataSource` of the first ListBox. You can get the selected year (`SelectedIndexChanged` event) with

```
int year = (int)listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

With this year, you can get the cars list with

```
var selectedCarList = _carsByYear[year];
```

Assign it to the `DataSource` of the second  ListBox.

Comment: I kept getting an error" An item with the same key has already been added." on code _carsByYear.Add(year, cars);

Comment: Check to see if the key exists already.  If it doesn't, you create a new list and add it with the year as the key.  If the key already exists, you simply retrieve the existing list.  See edited coded above; I left blank lines in-between to show where the slight changes are.

Comment: now the is no error but nothing displayed. This is a very challenging assignment. everyone in my class is stuck. Your help is appreciated Ide_Mind

Comment: @Idle_Mind: I kept your idea but used `TryGetValue` instead of `ContainsKey` to be able to test and retrieve in one single operation. @F.David: If the file contains the same year more than once, my original code attempted to insert the same year used as key into the dictionary. Each key must be unique in a dictionary. Idle_Mind's and my edits are now checking for an existing matching year list and use this one instead creating a new list. This solution only addresses the logic part, not the user interface part. (Since this an assignment, I cannot give you the entire solution.)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I always forget about `TryGetValue()`.  NIce.

Answer (score 0):

> now the is no error but nothing displayed. This is a very challenging
>   assignment. everyone in my class is stuck.

Works fine for me.  Here's a variation with some examples of how you could use it:

[image]

```
private readonly SortedList<int, SortedSet<string>> _carsByYear = new SortedList<int, SortedSet<string>>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SortedSet<string> cars = null;
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
        "cars.txt");

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(line, out int year))
            {   // We have a year
                if (!_carsByYear.ContainsKey(year))
                {
                    cars = new SortedSet<string>();
                    _carsByYear.Add(year, cars);
                }
                else
                {
                    cars = _carsByYear[year];
                }
            }
            else
            {   // We have a car
                if (!cars.Contains(line))
                {
                    cars.Add(line);
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = _carsByYear.Keys.ToList();
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        listBox2.DataSource = _carsByYear[(int)listBox1.SelectedItem].ToList();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1 && listBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        int year = (int)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        string car = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        label1.Text = year.ToString();
        label2.Text = car;
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "";
        label2.Text = "";
    }
}
```

If you still can't get it to work, give **MORE DETAILS** about the contents of the file and how you're supposed to use it in your interface.

Comment: I think the issue is with my file being in debug\bin and I don't know how to fix it. I put "cars.txt" instead of the file name and the program crash.

Comment: I had an issue with file path because it was in the bin and I fix it. May God bless you for your help.